# Access iOS filesystem without jailbreak?

Tags: ios, ssh, copy, filesystems, usb

I would like to write/use an open source script that can access iOS filesystem (non-jailbroken). On a Jailbroken device, i use `ssh`/`scp` to access, **transfer data from** the device. Intent is to copy some part of the **iOS filesystem** (say `/var/mobile/Applications/xxx-xxxx/Documents`) to a Mac, from a **non-Jailbroken device**, **using** some **script**. I see that tools like iFunBox is able to do it. Would like to know it manages to do so.

I came across [mobiledevice.h](http://theiphonewiki.com/wiki/MobileDevice_Library) but could not really understand how to use it.

Also, would prefer getting this done over USB.. for a jailbroken device, i use [tcprelay.py](http://code.google.com/p/iphone-dataprotection/source/browse/usbmuxd-python-client/tcprelay.py?r=1eae3bba5cd2713a372f6eff64e2778ba9d864e4) for doing the **usb tunneling**. Is there something i can use for a non jailbroken device?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The MobileDeviceManager library](https://github.com/xslim/mobileDeviceManager) brings us simple filesystem operations (it's an easy-to-use Objective-C wrapper around the MobileDevice framework you have come across).

The thing is that it doesn't support copying files **from the device to the computer,** only the other way around. So, in order to work around this issue, I've created a patch ([GitHub gist](https://gist.github.com/H2CO3/6148191)) that you can merge into the included sample program to have it understand the `copyFrom` command.

Comment: Thanks for the solution and snippet in such short time\m/ The concern I have is about MobileDeveiceManager's License. A compliance tool flagged this out and I wont be able to use this solution. However, I found another wrapper for mobile device.h.. mobiledevice by imkira (https://github.com/imkira/mobiledevice) This is an MIT licensed and I won't not face any issues. Would be great if it would be possible for you to help me with a similar snippet that I can plug-in to mobiledevice. I will make sure to give proper credits to you and imkira, in all the documentations regarding the same.

Comment: @Ocelot Excuse me but what exactly is the problem with **this** solution?

Comment: Your solution works perfectly fine. It solves the question to the point. The issue is with redistribution of MobileDeviceManager. The compliance tool identified it as GPL License. So, I would not be able to use MobileDeviceManager. That is the reason why I have requested you to help me out with using mobiledevice for the same.

Comment: @Ocelot I see. However, it's **not** under GPL, I don't know what the stupid programmers of the even more stupid compliance tool are doing... Also, the "snippet in short time" is an illusion. I've spent quite a few time digging theough the library, and I've already had the code snippet, it's just that I haven't uploaded it to GitHub. I am really sorry, but I don't have the time to do this immediately for the second time. You may want to look at the `AFCFile*()` API [here](http://theiphonewiki.com/wiki/MobileDevice_Library), I think you will be able to do something useful with it.

Comment: Thanks for the directions :)

Answer (score 6):

You can install the ifuse tool, which is hosted here: https://github.com/libimobiledevice/ifuse

In order to compile this tool, you will need the a working set of Gnu-tools (make, libtool, etc).

```
#Don't worry - clang is still default
sudo port install gcc48
```

**NB: Update your .bash_profile (or similar) to include the following:**

```
#Important - this is where your compiled libs will get installed to, so we need this
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/**
```

***The rest of this process should take a few minutes***

**Install fuse4x**

```
sudo port install fuse4x
```

**Build the dependencies:**

Check out: https://github.com/libimobiledevice/libplist, cd into the checkout, and run:

```
./autogen.sh
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Check out: https://github.com/libimobiledevice/libusbmuxd, cd into the checkout, and run:

```
./autogen.sh
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Check out: https://github.com/libimobiledevice/libimobiledevice, cd into the checkout, and run:

```
./autogen.sh
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

(If you're on Linux you'll also need to install usbmuxd, after building libusbmuxd and libimobiledevice. . otherwise, for Windows and OSX . . . )

**Now build iFuse:**

Check out: https://github.com/libimobiledevice/ifuse

```
./autogen.sh
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

**To use ifuse to access your app's documents directory:**

Make a mount directory:

```
sudo mkdir -p /Volumes/myapp.app
```

Now mount the app's dir:

```
ifuse --container <appid> /Volumes/abced.app
```

Where app id is the name what's displayed in the bundle identifier . . **example:**

```
 ifuse --container mycompany.ABCED.com /Volumes/abced.app/
```

(Refer to the attached pic)

[image]

Comment: I tried ifuse with the guide above, but my macbook crashed, os x yosemite 10.10.2 with iPhone 5c 8.1, did you have ever encounted this? Thank you!

Comment: I don't have it currently installed but managed to compile with MacPorts on Yosemite

Comment: I've had success with the `--documents` argument, to mount an app's documents-folder. What is the advantage of the `--container` argument?

Comment: @NoBugs I think it mounts the whole app container (Library, other dirs) not just the docs dir.