# Is there an iTunes C++ library for Windows that allows access to a USB-connected iOS device's filesystem?

Tags: c++, ios, windows, itunes

I've been looking for any library that allows access to the iOS filesystem, and I haven't found anything yet. The COM SDK is only for iTunes itself, not for its connected devices.

Basically I'm looking for the functionality that programs like [iFunbox](http://i-funbox.com/) use.

Answer (score 0):

Check out ifuse - a cross platform tool. Url: https://github.com/libimobiledevice/ifuse

Detailed instructions on compiling and using it are [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18037591/access-ios-filesystem-without-jailbreak/20568346#20568346).